# how to give width of image card in PageView widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, card

I wanted to create pageview like in the following image:
[figma design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlClb.jpg)

But all I had is like in the following image:
[my flutter pageview widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxszd.jpg)

Pageview is taking full width of viewport. How can I make my pageview like in the first image.
My code is the following:

```
  Container(
                child: Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        child: PageView(
                          controller: controller,
                          children: imgList
                              .map((item) => Card(
                                    // semanticContainer: true,
                                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      item,
                                      height: 150,
                                      width: 50,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    ),
                                  ))
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: Check the BoxFit values, atm I can't but something other than .fill could make this done.

Comment: Also can try to place them in a SizedBox

Comment: i think it will easy to handle using `carousel_slider `

Answer (score 5):

try to change the viewport by using pageviewcontroller:

```
  PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);
  }
```